# Pandas: join series based on category index

Tags: python, pandas, join, indexing, categories

I have two pd.Series:

```
          A
idx    
200  1
300  2
400  3
```

with length n and

```
          B
idx    
200  4
350  5
360  6
370  7
380  8
```

with length m.
Note that the length of the Series can be different.

I would like to have a category index:

```
cat
[200, 300)
[300, 400)
[400, 500)
```

and perform a correlation between the following pd.Series:

```
                        A      B
cat
[200, 300)   1         3 
[300, 400)   2         4+5+6+7
[400, 500)   3         NaN
```

So how do I slot my data based on their index into the category index and perform a sum over entries that fall into the same category?
I tried around with groupby but I do not manage to groupby over Categories.
THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

Data setup:

```
a = pd.Series(data=[1,2,3],index=[200,300,400])
b = pd.Series(data=[4,5,6,7,8], index=[200,350,360,370,380])
```

Convert to dataframe and create category using `pd.cut`

```
df_a = a.to_frame()
df_a['cat']  = pd.cut(df_a.index,bins=[0,100,200,300,400,500,600], labels=['0-99','100-199','200-299','300-399','400-499','500-599'])

df_b = b.to_frame()
df_b['cat'] = pd.cut(df_b.index,bins=[0,100,200,300,400,500,600], labels=['0-99','100-199','200-299','300-399','400-499','500-599'])
```

Do `groupby` on cat and use `pd.concat`

```
group_b = df_b.groupby('cat')[0].apply(list)
group_b = group_b.where(group_b.str.len())

group_a = df_a.groupby('cat')[0].apply(list)
group_a = group_a.where(group_a.str.len())

pd.concat([group_a,group_b],axis=1,keys=['A','B'])
```

Output:

```
           A             B
cat                       
0-100    NaN           NaN
101-200  [1]           [4]
201-300  [2]           NaN
301-400  [3]  [5, 6, 7, 8]
401-500  NaN           NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Does as advertised, except I had to use `group_b = df_b.groupby('cat')[0].sum()` instead of `group_b = df_b.groupby('cat')[0].apply(list)` to obtain my desired result.

Comment: Ah... I thought you wanted a list of values and not the actual sums.  Good deal, I am glad it worked out. Cheers.